# ajaxform not submit the value if attachment is not available

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, ajaxform

I am a beginner in Java and go to create one web application. I am submitting one form to controller using [ajaxform](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). There are few elements and one of them is `type=file`.

my controller method is as following

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/addReplies" }, method = {
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST,
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET } )
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Object> addReplies(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("Replies") Replies replies,
        BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,Locale locale,Principal principal,
        @RequestParam(value = "fileData2",required=false) CommonsMultipartFile fileData2[]) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
             //perform some opraton
        }
```

this everything is work properly if there is attachment available in data otherwise it does not go into this method.

if I remove `@RequestParam(value = "fileData2",required=false) CommonsMultipartFile fileData2[]` this parameter from method then work well but by this way I cannot get the attachment.

please try to understand my question and as soon as give me all possible solution.

This method is working well if I am not using ajax and submit form with regul

Answer (score 0):

i also do this 
but my coding also working

do this solution

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveUserTask", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,String> saveUserTask(
        @RequestParam( value = "title" , required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam( value = "projectid" , required = false) int projectid,
        @RequestParam( value = "mileid" , required = false,defaultValue ="-1") int mileid,
        @RequestParam( value = "responsible" , required = false) int responsible[],
        @RequestParam( value = "startDate" , required = false) Date startDate,
        @RequestParam( value = "endDate" , required = false) Date endDate,
        @RequestParam( value = "description" , required = false) String description,
        @RequestParam( value = "priority" , required = false, defaultValue="1") int priority,
        @RequestParam( value = "workHours" , required = false) int workHours,
        @RequestParam(value = "attachment" , required = false) MultipartFile myFile,
        HttpServletRequest request,Principal principal,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,Locale locale) throws ParseException, IOException{
    String fileAttachPath;
    if(myFile!=null)
        fileAttachPath=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/attechments/"+ new Date().getTime() + "_" + myFile.getOriginalFilename());
    else
        fileAttachPath="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For uploading a file normally you need to use encType="multipart/form-data" in your form. If you want to use Ajax to upload a file, Along with Simple ajax call you need to use its methods

or

whey you are uploading the file, before Serialize the ajaxForm first check is it filepart is null or not, if its null then disable the element for longer availability and submit

```
beforeSerialize: function($form, options){
//before serializing the data have to disable element if the data is not avaliable
         $(".attachfile").filter(function(){ 
              return !this.value; }).attr("disabled", "disabled");
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try this before to submit ajax form data object?

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/settingsSim",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public Map uploadSimSettings(@RequestBody String body) {
    /*
    some controller logic 
    */
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
$("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
    // tasks to do  with ajax submit
});
```

And things worked perfectly.

See this api [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) for more specific details.